# Regex for Capybara

Tags: ruby, regex, capybara

Can I use RegEx with Capybara?

I am trying to do somth like

> fill_in \firstName" type="text" name="(\w+)" value=""\, :with =>
>   'sdsdsd'
>    Capybara answers
>
> Сapybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find field \firstName\"
>   type=\"text\" name=\"(\w+)\" value=\"\"\

Wrong syntax?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It would help if you show the html of the element that you are trying to get.

Answer (score 1):

You do not begin and end a regexp with backslashes \likeso\, you normally need slashes /likeso/. There is also the %r syntax that allows for different delimitors, see http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Regexp.html

But all this does not apply in this case, because:

You cannot use a regexp as the first argument of fill_in, only a String. See the documentation at http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Node/Actions:fill_in

You can use either the id, name or the label-text to locate
the input field, so just using "firstName" should work for you:

```
 fill_in 'firstName', :with => 'sdsdsd'
```

Comment: In fact I am trying to use regex to find \firstName" type="text" name="(\w+)" value=""\ what is in brackets (\w+) - as the result it should give me the name

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. In fact I know the syntax fill_in 'firstName', :with => 'sdsdsd', just as the name field is very often changed, I want to find it with regex, because thus even it changes- I still can use it whatever it could be. Could you please give me advise how should I do in this case?  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You mixed up single and double quotes.

```
#       ⇓         ⇓
fill_in 'firstName"
```

Comment: In fact I am trying to use regex to find  \firstName" type="text" name="(\w+)" value=""\   what is in brackets (\w+) - as the result it should give me the name